# if error and vlookup in vba macros

Tags: vba, excel, formula, vlookup

My task to write a formula which includes if, iferror and Vlookup

I need to apply the formula till the end of last row which contains values .

if vlookup throws NA , then the cell should be blank , othewise the value should be replaced with numerical Value "1"

but when tried formula but it is giving error

```
Sub testt()

Dim l As Long

l = Sheets(1).Range("A1:A" & Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Count
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("d1").Formula = "=IF(iferror(vlookup(c2,$D:$D,1,false),""),"",1)"
        .Range("d1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("d1:d" & l), Type:=xlFillDefault

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: There are few things that don't make sense from your example.  For starters, your calculation for the last row uses Sheets(3) and Sheets(1) in the same formula, then Sheets("Sheet3") is used with the result.  Also, your 'IF' statement in the formula doesn't have a conditional value.  You should try your formula in the spreadsheet first.

Comment: @CuberChase : i changed the formula . Hope now u understand it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the IF part of the formula, in particular the logical test.  For a spreadsheet IF function the formula is:

```
=IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

The logical test is (from the Excel help file) any value or expression that can be evaluated to TRUE or FALSE. For example, A10=100 is a logical expression; if the value in cell A10 is equal to 100, the expression evaluates to TRUE. Otherwise, the expression evaluates to FALSE.

Your logical test is simply:

```
iferror(vlookup(c2,$D:$D,1,false),"")
```

Perhaps it should be:

```
iferror(vlookup(c2,$D:$D,1,false),"") = ""
```

Giving the formula (with 'The King's suggestion too):

```
"=IF(iferror(vlookup(c2,$D:$D,1,false),"""")="","",1)"
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought... in VBA you should use two " for every " in your formula...

Also, do you want to use IsError.

I would replace the formula as below

```
.Range("d1").Formula = "=IF(iserror(vlookup(c2,$D:$D,1,false)),"""",1)"
```

Otherwise, please let us know, what error you are getting.

Comment: it is not showing error , But the i am not getting the blank space in some cells and some cells "1" is not replacing the value